# How to set dot(.) at fixed place automatically in javascript?

Tags: javascript

[image]

Please consider the highlighted portion in the image I attached above.

In that portion I want to auto generate the dot after I add the respective digits as required in Field Length Field.

i.e.
Field :- Rate Per Unit
Consider the example of that field

Here I want to auto generate the dot(.) after I press 11.

Comment: So what do you have? A textbox, a string? How about for input — is that “*x* digit + Two Decimal Points” already parsed?

Comment: nope, I want to validate in same page...(in the text box)

Comment: That didn't really answer either of my questions. Show some code, please.

Comment: @rynah I just want to print dot(.) automatically after I type any two digits in textbox

i.e. suppose that I want to type 93465, then as I type 93, a dot would be auto generated and then other digits..

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for `.toFixed(2)`?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed